# algebra in $k[x,y,z]$ with exponents

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

have that $f=xy-z $ and $g=y-z$ and

$$\frac{k[x,y,z]}{xy-z,xz-z}$$

the s-polynomial of $f,g$ is $xz-z$

letting $i\geq 1 $ and $j \geq 1$ simplify $x^i z^j$

---

for $i<j$ 
$$\begin{aligned}
x^i z^j  &= \text{somehow}
  \\      &= z^i
\end{aligned} $$

for $i > j$ (from Lecture)

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
x^i z^j&= x^j z^j x^{i-j}
  \\      &= (xz)^jx^{i-j}
   \\     &=z^j x^{i-j} &&   \text{since } xz=z
     \\   &=z^j  &&  \text{??}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Not sure how $z^j$ was derived is $x^{i-j}=1$ ??

**if it is unclear the question boils down to explain the** $??$ steps

_______________________________________________________________-

**Attempt 2]** when reading $i$ and $j$ look the same to me sometimes switching to $i$ and $J$

for $i > j $
$$\begin{aligned}
  x^{i}z^{j}&= x^{i}z^{J}
\\           &=x^{i}z^{J +i - i}
   \\        &=x^i z^{J-i} z^i
  \\   &= x^i z^i z^{J-i}
\\ &= (xz)^i z^{J-i} && \text{ since }  xz=z
\\ &= (z)^i z^{J-i}
\\ &= z^J
\\ &= z^j
\end{aligned} $$

Comment: What does $g$ have to do with anything?

Comment: it has evrything to do with it. $S(xy-z,g)=xz-z$.

Comment: That doesn't explain why $g$ has anything to do with the problem. It's true that $S(xy-z, x-1) = g$, but that doesn't mean $x-1$ is at all relevant!

Comment: I dont have time to argue. Got it . I get my $i,j $ mixed up.  all is left is to type up case for $i <j $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relations allow you to replace $xz$ by $z$, hence
\begin{align*}
\text{}\\[0pt]
\text{For }&i < j,\\[6pt]
x^i z^j  &= (xz)^i z^{j-i} \\[6pt]
&= z^i z^{j-i}\\[6pt]
&= z^j\\[6pt]
\text{}\\[0pt]
\text{For }&i\ge j,\\[6pt]
x^i z^j  &= x^{i-j}(xz)^j\\[6pt]
&= x^{i-j}z^j\\[6pt]
&= z^j\qquad\text{[by the previous part]}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Actually, my argument above is flawed.

I had the illusion that $i-j < j$.

To fix it, keep going ...

From $x^{i-j}$ to $x^{i-2j}$ to $x^{i-3j}$ ... until the exponent is less than $j$, at which point, you can then apply the previous part.

Alternatively, proceed by induction.